# How to filter out "TCP Fast Retransmission" in Wireshark

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I'm analyzing the TCP traffic behavior in LTE network, and need to find out those TCP fast retransmission packets in a large pcap file.
In wireshark, what filter could be used to pick out all the [TCP Fast Retransmission] packets?

Comment: Flagging to move - not a programming question.

Comment: What means "flagging to move"?

Comment: It means this is forum is not the correct place for this question and its going to get moved to the right forum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html)

Here is some more detail on the [TCP analysis in Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP_Analyze_Sequence_Numbers)